# bokeh does not show the hours for the datetime on the x-axes

Tags: bokeh

I am using bokeh to plot some data and the format in the x-axes should be as `hours:minutes` like `00:20` for example.

So,  have the following:

```
stack = figure(sizing_mode='stretch_both',
               toolbar_location=None,
               tools="",
               title=title,
               x_axis_type='datetime')
stack_graph.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(hourmin = ['%H:%M'])
```

The source for the data is some dummy data which is created as:

```
source_data = dict(x=[datetime.strptime('00:05', '%H:%M'),
                      datetime.strptime('00:10', '%H:%M'),
                      datetime.strptime('00:15', '%H:%M'),
                      datetime.strptime('00:20', '%H:%M'),
                      datetime.strptime('00:25', '%H:%M')],
                      y1=[1, 2, 4, 3, 4],
                      y2=[1, 4, 2, 2, 3])
```

This is used to plot a vertical stack. However, the plot looks as follows:

[image]

if you look on the x-axes, the hours part is missing. I tried some combination of this time strings but cannot get the hours part to show.

Comment: You need to set 'seconds' to full format like this: https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/x-axis-datetime-display-not-rendering-full-format-for-smaller-range/8207/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DatetimeTickFormatter` has several properties that individually control formatting across different scales. The `hourmin` property controls formatting when the scales is large enough to encompass *multiple hours* but small enought that you still want to show minutes as some of major ticks. That is not the case with the plot you have above, which does not span even a single hour. You want to set the `minutes` property, which controls formatting on scales that only span minutes, not hours. If you want the same format across *all* scales, you will need to set *all* the properties. They are all listed [in the documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.formatters.DatetimeTickFormatter).